# How to deal with poker community that play without bankroll management

Tags: tournament, bankroll-management

I live in a country where poker is not legal. The online way I can play online and home games.

However, in my playing community, they don't care about bankroll management and try to play bigger and bigger stakes
(moving from one home game to another home game with different stakes). Exactly, they lose big but the thing that made me post this is
we're going to join tournaments such as APT/WPT next year (Vietnam, Taiwan maybe, yes without bankroll but pay from salary).
After committing that we're going to join early this year, I'm trying to build my bankroll online silently. However, now it's too far from 100 BIs of APT.

IMO, playing live tournaments without proper bankroll to play that stake is a weak mindset (they're arguing that "this is for experience", "just one time",
"building bankroll takes time too much", etc.).

I thought this is a self-destructive mindset, please advise me on how to improve the community like this.

Comment: the best way to build a BR is to win it, that way it is more likely not to be a fluke od deviation and you can somewhat validate your play to have a positive EV. the worst way is to cash your 401K or sale the house. Tournaments or a good way, I know many players that catapulted after tournament wins, and never looked back.

Comment: Yes, seems like shot-taking.

Comment: I would not argue that your describing it as shot taking is not a valid point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are following the rules of the game (or tournament or the house rules at a home game or whatever) then it is up to them what they do with their money.

If they are making mistakes such that they lose money they did not need to, then remember it is gambling. If they make mistakes such that you can win money, this is a standard part of the process. Lessons cost money. If they lose to you then don't tell them they are doing anything wrong, just quietly take your winnings.

If they are doing it to play "mind games" then remember that this also is part of the game. You need strategy to cope with a player who uses psychological games. Keep your eyes open for anything that might violate tournament rules and do not do such actions. Then find ways to reflect their mind games back on them so it is them who gets annoyed.

I recall a friendly little local "penny ante" game. A big pot would be $3. Usually most of the players would make their bet or fold or whatever very quickly, and the hand would move quite quickly. One player would stop and "think" for several minutes while everybody else squirmed. So I waited for it to be my turn and I sat and looked at him for two minutes, then folded. After I did that three or four times, he stopped delaying.

If you find that you cannot ignore them, and if it annoys you, then find another table to play at.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it helps so much.

Comment: "Lessons cost money." This is a good light-hearted note to start the new year. If their mistakes leads to your profits you have no reason to educate them and if they aren't figuring out how to make it back into the positives they will eliminate themselves from the pool when the time comes and they have no more stakes anyways.

Comment: I tried to educate them twice, but for now, I don't anymore.